# Arduino + PHP + MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arduino, xampp

Galera, sei pouco de PHP ai estou com umas dúvidas... Estou querendo implementar uma conexão de dos três sistemas citados no título.
A idéia é capturar dois valores de sensores e enviar para o php e depois ao mysql. Só que antes disso, estou com problemas para enviar esses dados e mostrar na página php... Estou utilizando o xampp v3.2.2 com php7.0 .
A idéia do código é pegar um ip e printar no serial, após isso, ao apertar a tecla '1' o arduino deveria enviar dados e requisitar algo do php, assim como, a partir daí, ser possível visualizar os dados tanto no serial quanto na página.

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>

byte mac[] = {0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED};
byte servidor[] = {192, 168, 1, 67};
#define portaHTTP 80
EthernetClient clienteArduino;

//=============================================================
//  AREA PARA A DECLARACAO DOS SENSORES
float sensor1 = 1;
float sensor2 = 3;
float sensor3 = 5;
//=============================================================

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Ethernet.begin(mac);

  if(Ethernet.begin(mac)== 0){

    Serial.println("Falha ao conectar a rede."); 
    Ethernet.begin(mac); 
  }

  Serial.print("Conectado a rede,no IP: ");
  Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());
}

void loop() {
//=============================================================
//  AREA PARA A LEITURA DOS SENSORES

//=============================================================


  if(clienteArduino.available()){
    char dadosRecebidos = clienteArduino.read();
    Serial.print(dadosRecebidos);  
  }

  if(!clienteArduino.connected()){
    clienteArduino.stop();  
  }

  char comando = Serial.read();

  if(comando == '1'){

   sensor1++;
   sensor2++;
   sensor3++;

   Serial.println("Conectando ao servidor e enviando dados: ");
   Serial.print("Sensor1: ");
   Serial.println(sensor1);
   Serial.print("Sensor2: ");
   Serial.println(sensor2);
   Serial.print("Sensor3: ");
   Serial.println(sensor3);

   if(clienteArduino.connect(servidor,portaHTTP)){

    //http://192.168.1.67/arduino_v3/teste.php?sensor1=5&sensor2=7&sensor3=9

     //clienteArduino.println("GET /arduino_v3/teste.php HTTP/1.0");

     clienteArduino.print("GET /arduino_v3/teste.php");
     clienteArduino.print("?s1=");
     clienteArduino.println(sensor1);
     clienteArduino.print("&s2=");
     clienteArduino.println(sensor2);
     clienteArduino.print("&s3=");
     clienteArduino.println(sensor3);
     clienteArduino.println(" HTTP/1.0");

     clienteArduino.println("HOST: 192.168.1.67 ");
     clienteArduino.println("Connection: Close");
     clienteArduino.println();


   } else {
      Serial.println("Falha na conexao com o servidor.");

   } 
  }



  //delay(3000);
}
```

Não entendo o motivo deste erro. No sensor 2 recebido e sensor 3 recebido...
[image: Não entendo o motivo deste erro. No sensor 2 recebido e sensor 3 recebido...]

Não entendo o motivo deste erro. Se eu preencho as requisições direto na url, não tenho esse problema... quando eu espero obter pelo arduino, acontece isso.
[image: Não entendo o motivo deste erro. Se eu preencho as requisições direto na url, não tenho esse problema... quando eu espero obter pelo arduino, acontece isso.]

Código PHP:

```
<?php
    $s1 = $_GET['s1'];
    $s2 = $_GET['s2'];
    $s3 = $_GET['s3'];

    echo "Sensor 1 Recebido: ".$s1;
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "Sensor 2 Recebido: ".$s2;
    echo "<br/>";
    echo "Sensor 3 Recebido: ".$s3;
?>
```

Comment: Esse é o código completo do php que vc está usando?

Comment: No print que você enviou, vc está tentando acessar a url sem passar os parametros s1, s2 e s3. Não entendo de arduino, mas aparentemente, nele está funcional

Comment: @EvertonNeri no arduino ele está quebrando linha em lugar indevido, por isso só o s1 vai, e o s2 e s3 falham. Veja a explicação na resposta postada. Atente para o print mandado pelo Arduino: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVKJP.png - o s1 foi bem, não deu erro, pq foi antes do `println` do valor. Os itens seguintes não, pois foram considerados como fazendo parte das linhas seguintes

Comment: @EvertonNeri foi o que o Bacco explicou mesmo. Funcionou parcialmente... porém ao acessar a url nada acontece. Parece que eu não estou concatenando o php da forma correta ou a informação não chega ao php... não sei como realizar um debug para essa questão.

Comment: Resolvido, eu viajei aqui uma hora. Mas vcs abriram meus olhos, já estava bitolado. Obrigadão mesmo pessoal. Valeu !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seu problema é usar `println()`. O correto é `print()` nesse caso.

```
 clienteArduino.print("GET /arduino_v3/teste.php");
 clienteArduino.print("?s1=");
 clienteArduino.print(sensor1);
 clienteArduino.print("&s2=");
 clienteArduino.print(sensor2);
 clienteArduino.print("&s3=");
 clienteArduino.print(sensor3);
 clienteArduino.println(" HTTP/1.0"); // Aqui sim é pra ter quebra, acabou a linha

 clienteArduino.println("HOST: 192.168.1.67 ");
 clienteArduino.println("Connection: Close");
 clienteArduino.println();
```

A linha da requisição é uma só. O `println()` quebra linhas. Pode notar que o `s1` tinha ido direito pelo Arduino.

No caso do teste direto pelo *browser*, é normal dar erro nas 3 variáveis, visto que você não colocou a *querystring*.

Answer (score -3):

Seu código não está interpretando método get por completo, dá para, por exemplo, ver literalmente tudo (para testes), no arquivo php:

Dá para saber literalmente tudo que está indo por querystring :).

Isso que citei foi para LER TODO MÉTODO GET, mas no caso talvez seu arduíno não esteja enviando os parâmetros...

Answer (score -3):

Sei que o post é antigo, mais se alguém estiver procurando vai lá:
O erro da página é referente ao PHP, não ao arduino.
Vc declarou as 3 variáveis ($s1, $s2 e $s3) com os valores recebidos pela superglobal $_GET[].Essa superglobal só "existe" se haver o GET, mais ao acessar a página vc não passou os valores por GET, então o PHP não define as váriáveis pq o valor não existe.
Para ele printar os valores e não dar o erro passe os parâmetros:
localhost/arduino_v3/teste.php?s1=VALOR1&s2=VALOR2&s3=VALOR3
Ou faz um condicinal na definição da variável:

```html
<?php

$s1 = $_GET['s1']? $_GET['s1'] : 's1 Não definida';
$s2 = $_GET['s2']? $_GET['s2'] : 's2 Não definida';
$s2 = $_GET['s3']? $_GET['s3'] : 's3 Não definida';
```

Comment: É legal você querer ajudar, mas é importante ler com atenção e analisar a situação toda antes de postar. O problema é que no lado do arduino o GET estava sendo montado errado. O aviso do PHP é só consequência (e se o erro fosse esse, a postagem seria uma duplicata de outra existente que já trata disso). Seu código simplesmente trocou o warning do PHP por um warning seu. A solução (que inclusive o autor marcou como correta) foi arrumar o código do arduino que era onde estava o problema, vide imagem do problema real: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVKJP.png (o s1 foi passado, o resto não)